# Calling function on animation step

Tags: jquery

I would like to call a function several times while slideToggling a div. I figured I should use the `step` property of `slideToggle()`

```
$('body').on('click', '#commentArticle', function(e) {
    $('#commentArticleForm').slideToggle({
        duration: 400,
        step: resizeOthers()
    }); 
});
```

For testing purposes:

```
function resizeOthers() {
    console.log("a");
}
```

I would expect `resizeOthers()` to be called several times while the animation is playing. By checking the console though it seems as though it's called only once (actually seems to happen before animation starts, just after clicking on element).

**What have I misunderstood?**

Comment: Just use `step: resizeOthers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the reference of that function, But you are calling the function

```
$('body').on('click', '#commentArticle', function(e) {
    $('#commentArticleForm').slideToggle({
        duration: 400,
        step: resizeOthers
    }); 
});
```

`()`  will simply call the function and it will assign the returned value of the invoked function to the step.